# How do I get to update my table values by clicking a button?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have this page where the employee leaves can be approve/reject by the admin. So far this is what I have:

```js
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['approved']))
{
    echo "Approved";
    $status=$_POST['status'];
}
if(isset($_POST['rejected']))
{
    echo "Rejected";
    $status=$_POST['status'];
}
?>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">

        <h3>
            Employee Leaves
        </h3>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>---</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                include ('database.php');
                $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM leaves order by id DESC");
                $result ->execute();
                for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action=""><input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input></form>
                            &nbsp
                            <form method="post" action=""><input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input></form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>

            <a href="home"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So I'm trying to get the value of `status` to update when I click on approve/reject.

Here's my table schema:

[image: Table Schema]

I think the last thing I need is the update query (not sure). I know there are tons of tutorials out there, I'm sorry but I just can't understand it. I think I'm gonna need a specific one.

Comment: What's the server-side error you get after running this code ? Or clicking the approve or reject button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a SQL query to update the database record once either action button is pressed.

Here is a hint:

```
$stmt = $database->prepare ("UPDATE leaves SET status = :status WHERE id = :row_id");
$stmt->execute(['status' => $status, 'record_id' => $record_id]);
```

Also note that you only need one form and you need to include the record id in the submission:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_message['id']; ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input>
   <input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a `form` in the loop to get the value of `status`. You may pass the `value` in an `<a href='page?approved=[status]'>` and get it when it's clicked.

You can do the following

```
<?php
for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    $id = $row_message['id']
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?approved=' .$row_message['status']?>">Approve</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?rejected=' .$row_message['status']?>">Rejected</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php   }   ?>
```

and get the value of status:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['approved']))
{
    echo "Approved";
    $status=$_GET['approved'];
}
if(isset($_GET['rejected']))
{
    echo "Rejected";
    $status=$_GET['rejected'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In these form elements, you need to add `action` (Where you process your form data).

In this case that's this page itself.

So, you can use the PHP file name or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` (PHP_SELF is a variable that returns the current script being executed).

So, your form elements should look like

```
<form method="post" action="this_file_name.php"><input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input></form>
&nbsp
<form method="post" action="this_file_name.php"><input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input></form>
```

OR

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>"><input type="submit" value="Approved" name="approved"></input></form>
&nbsp
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>"><input type="submit" value="Rejected" name="rejected"></input></form>
```